# I've edited and lost netbeans configuration file

Tags: netbeans-8

I'm using netbeans 8.0 as IDE , and I wanted to change the encoding of project files, I found a subject which gives the solution of this problem, so I decided to go change the netbeans.conf file inside the `/etc` directory of the program setup location, when I edited the file, I've got a message telling me that I couldn't edit the file while it's opened in another place, so I saved it in another place so that I could copy and replace the original one, and thus I lost the original file as a result I couldn't open Netbeans, pleas if any one can tell me where to find the netbeans.conf (on the internet if its possible) or any solution!

Comment: No need to edit any config file to change the project encoding. See the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E50453_01/doc.80/e50452/working_nbeans.htm#sthref120

Comment: thanks, for the moment i want just to get back the original conf file

Comment: ok then, I uninstall/reinstall it.